# Filter docker messages from syslog

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

Looks like docker is writing duplicate messages to syslog. For instance

```
Mar  6 23:53:45 ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx docker[45287]: 2019/03/06 23:53:45  GET 200  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx /cas/78008842b495e4cf1706b0932ee2b52288e8aa7fc9bcc07308dac831f9ddd9dc
Mar  6 23:53:45 ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx 0531bc03a15a[2921]: 2019/03/06 23:53:45  GET 200  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx /cas/78008842b495e4cf1706b0932ee2b52288e8aa7fc9bcc07308dac831f9ddd9dc
```

The contents of the messages are same do I would like to filter out one of them from syslog.

> process ID 2921 corresponds to /usr/bin/dockerd
>
> process ID 45287 corresponds to /usr/bin/docker run

I don't think the log is tagged by syslog, but I have tried the following and placed it in `/etc/rsyslog.d/docker.conf`. I am still seeing this message.

```
:programname, equals, "docker" ~
if ($programname == 'docker') then ~
```

Also tried

```
if $programname == 'docker' then /dev/null
& stop
```

Restarted rsyslog and then checked, but the messages are still showing up.
`sudo service rsyslog restart`

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? And what version of Docker?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and docker version is 18.03. I didn't name the file properly so the rule wasn't applied. Just answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around looks like I have to name the file under `rsyslog.d` with a number prefix. For instance I saved the file as `/etc/rsyslog.d/docker.conf` and after changing it to `/etc/rsyslog.d/01-docker.conf` the rules got applied.